# while read line in shell script - how to stop the loop?

Tags: shell-script

I read a tutorial here that I can use

```
while read line
do 
wget -x "http://someurl.com/${line}.pdf" -o ${line}.pdf
done < inputfile
```

However this script keeps running with $line not containing any value. 
How do I have to alter the code that the script stops if the next line is empty or some "signal" word occurs.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It will stop on end of file (not "empty line").

Comment: However i dont know where the EOF is. I created the inputfile totally new and only added the lines I needed. The script still didn't stop though

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you'd have the while-loop stop on a zero-length value of `line`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read line
do
    if [[ -z $line ]]
    then
         exit
    fi
    wget -x "http://someurl.com/${line}.pdf" 
done < inputfile
```

I think your real problem might lie in the unmatched double-quote character before "http", or the unmatched back-tick character at the end of "inputfile". You should clean up the quoting before trying my code example.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I will try it additionally to the example of PSkocik.
When do i have to use double brackets as in your example  [[  ]]
and when do I have to use only single [ ]  brackets as in the example below?

Thank you very much!
Unfortunately I can't vote because I have below 15 posts

Comment: Notice that I specified `/bin/bash` as the shell: if you use `bash`, you should use `[[` and `]]`. If you use something else, or you want to be backward compatible with everything, use `[` and `]`.

Comment: @BruceEdiger IMO, since you aren't actually using any of the advanced features that `[[` provides, I think a plain `[` is better. With `[` the script becomes plain POSIX, and you can use `/bin/sh` and likely get a couple of milliseconds' speed boost at startup. (+ `$line` -> `"$line"`).

Answer (score 5):

```
 while read line && [ "$line" != "quit" ]; do # ...
```

Or to stop at an empty line:

```
 while read line && [ "$line" != "" ]; do # ...
```

or

```
 while read line && [ -n "$line" ]; do # ...
```

---

On a different topic:

```
"http://someurl.com/$line.pdf" -o "$line.pdf"
```

you don't need the curlies, but you should use double quotes around the last variable expansion.

Comment: You don't "need" the curly brackets, but it doesn't hurt to use them -- and it may reinforce good practices.

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked out nice. 
Can you propose a tutorial on stuff like this. I'm at the moment on a learning by doing way.
Unfortunately I can't vote because I have below 15 posts

Comment: Can you explain your last solution with -n. What does this command lead to? Thank you!

Comment: @user42469 Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624520/why-doesnt-my-if-statement-work-properly-in-bash/34624704#34624704 . It explains `[ ]`. Then you can type `help test` to learn about things such as `!=` or `-n`.

Comment: As for a tutorial, IDK. Going through `man dash` might not be a bad idea (man bash is kid of large if you're new to all the shell stuff).  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide looks good. Then practice, manpages, and help pages for shell routines.

Answer (score -1):

```
        line=\ ; PS4='${#line}: + '
        while   read line <&$((${#line}?0:3))
        do      : "$line"
        done    <<msg 3</dev/null
        one nice thing about allowing shell expansions to self test
        is  that the shell already has mechanisms in place for the
        evaluation. its doing it all the time anyway. theres almost
        nothing for you to do but to let it fall into place.
        For example:
        ${line##*[ :: i doubt very seriously the shell will read any of this :: ]*}
msg
```

---

```
1: + read line
59: + : 'one nice thing about allowing shell expansions to self test'
59: + read line
58: + : 'is  that the shell already has mechanisms in place for the'
58: + read line
59: + : 'evaluation. its doing it all the time anyway. theres almost'
59: + read line
52: + : 'nothing for you to do but to let it fall into place.'
52: + read line
12: + : 'For example:'
12: + read line
0: + : ''
0: + read line
```

Alternatively, for an immediate break upon reading a blank line...

```
while   read line && ${line:+":"} break
do    : stuff
done
```

...will work nicely.